# subset of positive matrices such that the Loewner order is total

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Are there known characterizations of subsets of positive matrices over which the  [Loewner order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order)  is total ?

Comment: Unless the subset is the positive span of a single matrix, then your subset won't have much structure. Notice that for 2x2 matrices (generalizable to any dimension), this is equivalent to ask for a set of centered 2D ellipses that are contained in each other, i.e. where the containment order is total

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why the other subset won't have much structure ?